# Как правильно: "не разрывая поцелуй" или "не разрывая поцелуя"?

Tags: склонение

Прошу прощения за такой глупый вопрос, но как будет правильно: "не разрывая поцелуй" или "не разрывая поцелуя"? Встречались оба варианта.

Answer (score 2):

Возможны оба варианта:

Не разрывая **поцелуй** (В.п)  и не разрывая **поцелуя** (Р.п.)

Р.п. используется при отрицании (поцелуй **вообще**) и чаще в **книжной** речи.

В.п. заменяет Р.п. при ослаблении отрицания в **разговорной** речи и при указании на **конкретный** предмет (этот поцелуй).

**ПРАВИЛО**

**[§201. Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm)**

2. **Винительный падеж,** ослабляющий значение отрицания, обычно употребляется в следующих случаях:

1. при указании **на конкретный объект** («именно этот предмет, а не вообще какой-то»): не отрецензировал рукопись, которую ему прислали; не выпила молоко, которое ей оставила мать. Например: Он не отвергнул тогда с презрением эти сто рублей (Достоевский); Не наклоняй знамя-то... (Горький);

3. **Факультативное** употребление родительного и винительного падежа при переходном глаголе с отрицанием связано со **стилистическим** различием: конструкции с родительным падежом характерны для **книжной** речи, конструкции с винительным падежом – для речи **разговорной**.

Answer (score 2):

Как риторический оборот, для описания состояния, которое поцелуем уже не является, но сохраняет связь с поцелуями - не разрывая поцелуя. Речь не *о поцелуе* или *о поцелуя как* о чём-то ещё.

*Когда они, наконец, расстались у перекрёстка, он ещё долго шёл, никуда не сворачивая, не отпуская воспоминания, не разрывая поцелуя.*

Как единичное действие, фактическое, конкретный один поцелуй, конкретный момент времени - не разрывая поцелуй. Речь о поцелуе, действии.

*Выполняем упражнение, высоко поднимая колени, не разрывая поцелуй.*

Они вошли из гостиной в прачечную не разрывая поцелуя. ~ Они вошли вместе, они вошли целуясь.

Они вошли из гостиной в прачечную не разрывая поцелуй. - тут нужно уточнить, что это был за "поцелуй", который они не разрывали, их это поцелуй или какой-то ещё. - Они вошли из гостиной в прачечную не разрывая поцелуй. И уже там смогли полностью его отстирать...

Comment: Это вам поисковик нашел такие предложения  или сами вдохновились (голос от меня)?)  А в Карте слов много реальных примеров с разрыванием поцелуя: Они не могли разорвать поцелуя, зная, что разорвав, снова станут ругаться и кричать друг на друга. https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словосочетанием/разорвал+поцелуй

Comment: @Sharon да не, я сам выдумал из головы, хочется же применить на практике сказанное.

Comment: Я догадалась, что не. Некоторые примеры уж очень сомнительного содержания)   Хотя в карте слов  тоже не лучше.  // Что-то редко заходите на форум, не помогаете нам.

Comment: @Sharon был очень занят, получал бан разделе политики)

Comment: Получили? И зачем он вам?

Comment: @Sharon не знаю, но тут видимо такие ачивки, когда дают, не можешь не взять...

Comment: Вот я и говорю, лучше уж будьте с нами.